# Does exec() release all the page frames in the physical address space of the calling process?

Tags: linux, exec, virtual-memory

From Operating System Concepts

> The kernel **creates a new virtual address space** in two situations:
>   when a process runs a new program with **the exec() system call** and
>   when a new process is created by the fork() system call. **The ﬁrst
>   case** is easy. When a new program is executed, the process is given a
>   new, completely empty virtual address space.  It is up to the routines
>   for loading the program to populate the address space with virtual
>   memory regions.

When a process runs a new program with `exec()`, it will create a new and empty **virtual address space**.  Does it also release all the page frames in the underlying **physical address space** of the process, or continue to use them?

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)#Effects

Comment: First, keep in mind that what you are reading only applies to Eunchs systems. The logical address space of the process is mapped to either virtual pages (on disk) or to physical page frames. The books is wrong stating "new, completely empty virtual address space." A new address space will always have a system area that is the same for all processes. The logical to physical mappings in the system space will stay in place. All mappings to physical page frames in the user space will be unmapped with a new address space. (Hint: Get a different book).